# Create Html table in php foreach loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, html-table

I'm facing a problem which i had create a html table in "Php foreach loop" to loop from Mysql data into the html table.

But when i have more than 1 row of data, it wont show in the same table but turn out to each row of data show in independent table.

```
<?php
    global $wpdb, $indeed_db;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userid = $user->ID; 
    $woo_orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp8u_wc_order_product_lookup");
    foreach ($woo_orders as $print ){
        $order_id = $print->order_id; 
        $woo_customer_id = $print->customer_id;  
        $woo_customer = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp8u_wc_customer_lookup where customer_id=$woo_customer_id");
        foreach($woo_customer as $print2){
            $current_user_uid = $print2->user_id;
        }
        $date1 = strtotime($print->date_created);
        $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);                                                                      
        $amount = $print->product_net_revenue;                                                                      
        if($userid == $current_user_uid){ ?>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order ID</th>
                            <th>My Customer ID</th>
                            <th>Create Date</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo "$order_id";?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "$woo_customer_id";?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "$date_created";?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "$amount";?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
        <?php }
}
?>
```

The output:

```
Order ID | My Customer ID |    Create Date         |   Amount   |
126        9                   2020-06-24 13:45:35     3000        <-- 1st row data
Order ID | My Customer ID |    Create Date         |   Amount   |
123        9                   2020-06-22 12:01:14     1000        <-- 2nd row data show in independent table
```

After doing some research, I try using this method but it turn out to the table only store 1st row of data, 2nd and after of row data show out side of the table instead of showing inside the table

```
<?php
    global $wpdb, $indeed_db;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userid = $user->ID; 
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Order ID</th>
                <th>My ID</th>
                <th>Create Date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php
    $woo_orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp8u_wc_order_product_lookup");
    foreach ($woo_orders as $print ){
        $order_id = $print->order_id; 
        $woo_customer_id = $print->customer_id;  
        $woo_customer = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp8u_wc_customer_lookup where customer_id=$woo_customer_id");
        foreach($woo_customer as $print2){
            $current_user_uid = $print2->user_id;
        }
        $date1 = strtotime($print->date_created);
        $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);                                                                      
        $amount = $print->product_net_revenue;                                                                      
        if($userid == $current_user_uid){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo "$order_id";?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "$woo_customer_id";?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "$date_created";?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "$amount";?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php }
}
?>
```

The output:

```
Order ID |  My ID | My Customer ID |    Create Date         |   Amount   | 
126         37          9               2020-06-24 13:45:35     3000       <-- 1st row data         

123 9 2020-06-22 12:01:14 2020-07-22 12:01:14 1000                         <-- 2nd row data show outside of the table
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM wp8u_wc_order_product_lookup JOIN wp8u_wc_customer_lookup USING (customer_id)`. Selects in loops are bad :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of your table is inside loop. make table header and footer outside loop.

```
<?php
    global $wpdb, $indeed_db;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userid = $user->ID; ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order ID</th>
      <th>My ID</th>
      <th>Create Date</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    $woo_orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp8u_wc_order_product_lookup"); foreach ($woo_orders as $print ){ $order_id = $print->order_id; $woo_customer_id = $print->customer_id; $woo_customer = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM
    wp8u_wc_customer_lookup where customer_id=$woo_customer_id"); foreach($woo_customer as $print2){ $current_user_uid = $print2->user_id; } $date1 = strtotime($print->date_created); $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1); $amount =
    $print->product_net_revenue; if($userid == $current_user_uid){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo "$order_id";?></td>
      <td><?php echo "$woo_customer_id";?></td>
      <td><?php echo "$date_created";?></td>
      <td><?php echo "$amount";?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php    }    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting form your first code sample You could simply move the table and head hatml outside the loop

```
<?php
    global $wpdb, $indeed_db;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userid = $user->ID; 
    $woo_orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp8u_wc_order_product_lookup");
    echo "table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order ID</th>
                            <th>My Customer ID</th>
                            <th>Create Date</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>";

    foreach ($woo_orders as $print ){
        $order_id = $print->order_id; 
        $woo_customer_id = $print->customer_id;  
        $woo_customer = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp8u_wc_customer_lookup where customer_id=$woo_customer_id");
        foreach($woo_customer as $print2){
            $current_user_uid = $print2->user_id;
        }
        $date1 = strtotime($print->date_created);
        $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);                                                                      
        $amount = $print->product_net_revenue;                                                                      
        if($userid == $current_user_uid){ ?>
                
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo "$order_id";?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "$woo_customer_id";?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "$date_created";?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "$amount";?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

        <?php }
        echo "</table>";
}
?>
```