# PHP foreach loop & html table - displaying duplicates

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-block-theme

I am utilizing WordPress, ACF, and PHP; I've created a custom block with the code below. Please let me know if more information is needed. I am still fairly new to this and not sure what all to include.

The following code is working as intended with the exception of duplicating results. I did attempt to following through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634765/create-html-table-in-php-foreach-loop) with no luck. The picture included show what it's currently displaying. It should list
APCS 207 Command Line Interface...
APCS 242 Computer & Network Management...
BUSI 270 Accounting Software Applications...
BUSI 353 Advanced Accounting I...

[image: list]

```
<table style="width: 800px;">
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Course Credits</th>
            </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php 
$rawcourses = get_field('course_selector'); 
$progcode_check_checked_values = get_field('prog_discipline_code'); 


$i = 0;


foreach($rawcourses as $rawcourse) : 

    if( have_rows('course_list', $rawcourse) ): ?>
        
            

        <?php // Grab all courses

        while( have_rows('course_list', $rawcourse) ) : the_row(); 

            // Look for selected code
            // $code = get_sub_field('discipline_code');
            if ($progcode_check_checked_values) : ?>

                <?php foreach ($progcode_check_checked_values as $progcode_check_value) : ?>
<tr>
                        <td><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal<?php get_sub_field('course_number');?><?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo strtoupper($progcode_check_value) ?>
                        <?php the_sub_field('course_number'); ?></a>  </td>
                        <td><?php echo get_the_title($rawcourse); ?> </td>
                        <td><?php the_sub_field('credits'); ?></td>
                        
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modal<?php get_sub_field('course_number');?><?php echo $i;?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><?php echo get_the_title($rawcourse); ?></h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                <?php $content_post = get_post($rawcourse);
                                $content = $content_post->post_content;
                                $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                                $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
                                echo $content; ?>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
</tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; 

        // End loop.
        endwhile; ?>

            
        

    <?php $i++; // No value.
    else :
        // Do something...
    endif;
    
endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>type here
```

Comment: Can you please explain the relationship of `$progcode_check_checked_values` to the course list? The `foreach ( $procode_check_checked_values )` is why you're getting duplicates, so we need to better understand what it's purpose is.

Comment: @Caleb - Custom Block – Course Selection uses $progcode_check_checked_values - checkbox field to check any discipline codes associated with a program; and $rawcourses - relationship field to select courses associated with discipline code. Courses can have multiple discipline codes assigned to them. When being displayed however, we want just the discipline code associated with that program.  Custom Post Type – Courses uses course_list - repeater field. Sub fields are Discipline Code (select), Course Number (number), Credits (number). Can assign multiple to a course.

Comment: The name is duplicated, however the course code is not. Where do these codes come from? How do you know what the correct one is?

Comment: @Wimanicesir At the end of the first <td> this code <?php echo strtoupper($progcode_check_value) ?> should actually be $code - it's commented out above the if ($progcode_check_checked_values), but I haven't been able to get that to work. Originally, this was using a textbox instead of checkboxes, but that created a lot of other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out. I added an if statement after the foreach($progcode_check_checked_values as $progcode_check_value). I was able to get the commented out $code = get_sub_field('discipline_code') to work as well. Updated code below.

```
<table style="width: 800px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Course Name</th>
        <th>Course Credits</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php 
    $rawcourses = get_field('course_selector'); 
    $progcode_check_checked_values = get_field('prog_discipline_code'); 
    $i = 0;
    
    foreach($rawcourses as $rawcourse) : 
        if( have_rows('course_list', $rawcourse) ): ?>
    
        <?php
        while( have_rows('course_list', $rawcourse) ) : the_row(); 
            $code = get_sub_field('discipline_code');
        
            if ($progcode_check_checked_values) : ?>
            
            <?php foreach ($progcode_check_checked_values as $progcode_check_value) : ?>
                <?php if ($progcode_check_value == $code ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal<?php get_sub_field('course_number');?><?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo strtoupper($progcode_check_value) ?><?php the_sub_field('course_number'); ?></a>  </td>
                        <td><?php echo get_the_title($rawcourse); ?> </td>
                        <td><?php the_sub_field('credits'); ?></td>
                        
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modal<?php get_sub_field('course_number');?><?php echo $i;?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><?php echo get_the_title($rawcourse); ?></h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <?php $content_post = get_post($rawcourse);
                                        $content = $content_post->post_content;
                                        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                                        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
                                        echo $content; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; 
        endwhile; ?>
        <?php $i++; 
        endif;
    endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```